# ¿como no permitir solo espacios en blanco en java?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

mi pregunta es bastante simple y a la vez confusa, lo que tengo es un update a base de datos en donde el usuario podrá modificar su nombre entre otras cosas, lo que necesito es que al modificar el nombre el usuario no meta el nombre en nulo (Lo cual si he conseguido) pero que tampoco meta varios espacios en blanco como si fueran un nombre, ya que los espacios en blanco no son datos nulos,
pero tampoco quiero usar una función que me elimine todos los espacios en blanco, ya que si el usuario introduce "Miguel Lopéz" quisiera que sea un nombre valido, pero que si el usuario introduce "   " sea invalido, a continuación dejo mi código:

```
 public void up() throws SQLException{
    int confirmar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea modificar los datos del usuario:\n"
    + nombresave + "?");

 if(confirmar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
String fe = nc.fecha();
    Connection con = Db.connect(url,userdb,passdb);
Ssql = "UPDATE usuarios SET username=?,updated_at=?,rol_id=?"
                + "WHERE username=?";
try{
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(Ssql);
String rol = nc.lvl(Db.connect(url,userdb,passdb),
        "SELECT * FROM roles WHERE nombre LIKE '%"+rolbox.getSelectedItem().toString()+"%'",
        "id");
    pst.setString(1, txt_nombre.getText() );
    pst.setString(2, fe);
    pst.setString(3, rol);
    pst.setString(4, nombresave );
     if(pst.executeUpdate() > 0){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos han sido modificados con éxito", "Operación Exitosa", 
                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }else{

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la actualización de los datos\n", "Error en la operación\n"+
                                              " Intentelo de nuevo.",
                                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

    }
      Db db = new Db();
       db.cerrarConexion();
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("error" +e);}

 }
 }
```

Y para la parte de los datos nulos utilizo algo así como:

```
 if(nuevo.length()==0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   "NO ESPACIOS EN BLANCO");
 }else{
 "EL RESTO DEL CODIGO"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas el método [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) podrás eliminar los espacios iniciales y finales del *string* y de este modo, detectas si solo ingresan espacios en blancos o si dejan el campo vacío.

El método se podría llamar `isBlank` y recibe el objeto donde está el *string* y retorna `true` si la cadena está vacía, de lo contrario, `false`.

**Código:**

```java
public static boolean isBlank(String str)
{
    return str.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Modo de uso:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println(isBlank(""));
    System.out.println(isBlank("    "));
    System.out.println(isBlank("Miguel Lopez"));
}
```

**Resultado por pantalla:**

```java
true
true
false
```

Comment: No está mal, pero si vas a hacer un método *isNull*, yo lo implementaría como *return (str == null) || str.trim().isEmpty();*, por el PLA. Si lo quieres tal como lo has implementado, yo lo llamaría antes *isEmpty* o *isBlank*.

Comment: @SJuan76 ¿A que te referís con PLA?

Comment: De hecho, pensándolo mejor, definitivamente evitaría el nombre *isNull*, salvo para *return str == null;*. Cualquiera que use ese método no esperará que " " devuelva *true*, por " " NO es null.

Comment: Principle of Least Astonishment, diseñar tus clases y métodos para que a quien los use le sorprendan lo mínimo y le sean lo más "naturales" posible (dentro de lo que es esta profesión).

Comment: @SJuan76 Le había puesto `isNull`, porque como null significaba vacío, pues pensé que estaba clara la intención del método. Aunque cuando documentas cada método indicando su descripción, creo que quedaría claro su uso. En fin, le cambiaré el nombre a `isBlank`..

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero usar una combinación de dos funciones [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) y [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--), de esta forma primeramente eliminarías los espacios en los extremos y revisarías si tiene contenido o no:

```
 nuevo = nuevo.trim();
 if(nuevo.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   "NO ESPACIOS EN BLANCO");
 }else{
   //"EL RESTO DEL CODIGO"
 }
```

---

esta es la documentación:

**[isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--)**: Devuelve verdadero si, y solo si, length () es 0.

**[trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--)**: Devuelve una cadena cuyo valor es esta cadena, con cualquier espacio en blanco inicial y final eliminado.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la propiedad trim();
Asi 
Textview.trim();